# How to correctly calculate the height of a table

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

How do you calculate the height of a flexgrid table in VB6 so that it only contains the number of filled rows.

Currently

```
myFlexGrid.Height = (myFlexGrid.CellHeight * myFlexGrid.Rows) ' paraphrased from code
```

comes out at about 3 pixels short per line. Adding in the magic number is a bit hackish and would like to accomplish this without having to resort to that.

**Update:**
To complicate matters it also needs to handle multiline cells.

Answer (score 2):

RS Coneley is close, but here is the correct way that accounts for all DPI settings:

```
Me.MSFlexGrid1.Height = Me.MSFlexGrid1.CellHeight _
                      * (Me.MSFlexGrid1.Rows + Me.MSFlexGrid1.FixedRows) _
                      + (Screen.TwipsPerPixelY * 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go

```
Me.MSFlexGrid1.Height = (Me.MSFlexGrid1.CellHeight) * (Me.MSFlexGrid1.Rows + _
Me.MSFlexGrid1.FixedRows) + 30
```

The 30 is to make it two pixels longer to show the black border running around the flexgrid.

Also disabling the vertical scrollbar helps as well.

Comment: Actually the 30 is not correct from what I can find: If a user is running in 120dpi mode then 12 twips is equal to 1 pixel. But this adding of a semi-arbitary number is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I've also just found it needs to handle multiline cells.

Comment: Unless the control explicitly supports an autoheight function or exposes the values of the height of every UI element you will not be able to avoid using magic numbers. This is because controls are designed as black boxes. It looks like your logic is going to get complex here I suggest wrapping the flexgrid inside of a control class and add the autoheight function in there so the code in your main routines remains clean.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code I came up with

```
    For i = 0 To fgrComments.Rows - 1
        'Set MSFlexGrid to appropriate Cell
        myFlexGrid.Row = i

        'Set textbox to match the selected cell
        txtSizer.Width = myFlexGrid.ColWidth(2)
        txtSizer.Font = myFlexGrid.Font
        txtSizer.Text = myFlexGrid.Text

        'Call API to determine how many lines of text are in text box
        lLinesOfText = SendMessage(txtSizer.hwnd, EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0&, 0&)

        ' Update the running values
        lTotalNumberOfRows = lTotalNumberOfRows + lLinesOfText
        lCurrentHeight = lCurrentHeight + myFlexGrid.CellHeight
    Next i

    ' resize the grid
    Dim iSpacers As Integer
    iSpacers = Screen.TwipsPerPixelY * lTotalNumberOfRows
    myFlexGrid.Height = lCurrentHeight + iSpacers
```

You will need to Declare the SendMessage ([see here to see how](http://vbcity.com/forums/topic.asp?tid=64808)) and the value of EM_GETLINECOUNT, but you should be able to do that yourself:-)

It doesn't remove the magic numbers but it does rationalise them which is close enough for me.